# Button event not being handled

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm porting a simulation I wrote years ago in Perl to Python and I'm having an issue of halting the main simulation loop when I click on the STOP button.

How it works:
There is a canvas that I draw to and a RUN and a STOP button. The RUN button starts the simulation and the STOP button stops the simulation. When the STOP button is clicked the `stop()` function sets the global flag `Run_sim` to 0 and the flag is checked in the main simulation loop `while Run_sim != STOP:`.

I know the `stop()` function is being called and setting the `Run_sim` flag when the simulation is not running because I tested it before adding the simulation loop code.

But when the simulation loop is running it appears when the STOP button is clicked the event is not processed and the `stop()` function is not called until I <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> from the terminal.

Any advice on how to fix this?

I removed the code that doesn't apply to this.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import math
import time
import tkMessageBox


def stop():
    global Run_sim
    Run_sim = STOP

    ###############
    #  main part of simulation
    ###############

    def display_cluster():

       while Run_sim != STOP:
                 .
                 .
                 .
           bunch of code here
                 .
                 .
                 .

       # end while Run_sim

    # end display_cluster()

    stop_button = Button(button_frame, text="Stop", fg="red", command = stop)
    stop_button.pack(side = 'left')
```

Comment: Is `display_cluster` running in the main thread? If so, you may be preventing the event loop from servicing any events while the `while` loop is running.

Comment: `display_cluster()`'s execution is likely preventing tkinter's own `mainloop()` from running, which will "hang" the GUI. The simplest way to prevent that is to have `display_cluster()`' periodically call the universal widget method [`update_idletasks()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) to allow user-events to be processed.

Comment: I tried adding **window.update_idletasks()** as the very first line in the simulation loop and It didn't work but when I ctl-C it stops and I can see what I wrote on the canvas which I wasn't able to see before. The **window.mainloop()** is the main GUI processing loop. Am I call the method correctly or is there more setup I need to do some where?

Comment: When I tried **window.update()** instead of **window.update_idletasks()** it started working. It actually solved another issue I had too. So I'm good to go. Thanks for tip. I appreciate it.